# List of Lists in Scheme

Tags: racket

I was wondering how I can combine certain lists together in Scheme.

In Particular, I want to combine together a list, such as:

```
 (list 20 (list 10 (list 5 0)))
```

into something like:

```
 (list 20 10 5 0)
```

Something simple would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Racket, there's a built-in function that does exactly what you need, it's called [`flatten`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._flatten%29%29):

```
(define lst (list 20 (list 10 (list 5 0))))
(flatten lst)
=> '(20 10 5 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? Have you considered writing a function that makes use of [cons](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._cons%29%29)?  or something like a [flatten](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Flatten_a_list#Scheme) function?